# Foreach loop to only cycle through specific range of files (php)

Tags: php, loops, foreach, glob

I have a list of html files in a directory:

```
1-foo.html
2-bar.html
3-foo.html
4-bar.html
5-foo.html
...
```

If I want to display just the 3 first ones with a foreach loop in PHP, I can do this:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach (glob("*.html") as $filename)
{
  include $filename;
  if (++$i == 3) break;
}
?>
```

But what if I want to display just the 3 next ones? I'd need a foreach loop that runs a specific number of times, like above, but I'd need that loop to start at position 4, instead of 1.

Can anyone think of a way to do that with foreach?

Comment: If you have to use a `foreach` - use `array_slice()` to extract part of the array first.

Comment: Apart from that array_slice is of course an elegant solution - `continue` exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```php
foreach (array_slice(glob("*.html"), 3, 3) as $filename)
{
  include $filename;
}
```

Comment: Wow, so neat, and shorter then my original code!